# AChartEngine y-axis labels are cut

Tags: android, achartengine

How do I know what margins to use in an AChartEngine chart to prevent the y-axis labels from being displayed outside the chart when it is set to fill a layout? Can I automatically resize the chart so that the y-axis labels always are visible, even if they contain more than 2-3 digits?

/Markus

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do this automatically, but you can tweak the values until it looks good. You can also rotate the labels when you have several digits values.

Comment: can you tell me what values to tweak..?

Answer (score 1):

This is what I used to deal with Y axis labels that can have differing numbers of digits.  Find your max Y value, round it to an int, convert to string and then count the length of the string.  The length of the string can be used to calculate a value for the Left margin.

```
//**** Find max y value of dataset
Ymax = getMaxValue(U_Limit);
if(Ymax < 10){
Ymax = 10;
}else{
Ymax = Ymax*1.1;
}

//****  Find int value of number of digits in max y value
int PLAY_FACTOR = text_label_size*.5  // you may have to play around with this value
int leftMargin = (Double.toString(Math.round(Ymax)).length())*PLAY_FACTOR;              
int margins[] = { 26, leftMargin, botMargin, 14 }; // Top,Left,Bottom,Right
renderer.setMargins(margins);
```

Answer (score 0):

Found a better solution, if you use setYLabelsVerticalPadding with a negative value you can move a little bit down the label... in this way the upper Y label will be visible no matter what.

Hope it helps.